# insert/update from web server or database

Tags: postgresql, database-design, application-design

I have a data-model on the front-end that I want to insert/update in the database which of the following approaches (or neither!) is considered best practice:

```
# in webserver

some_model = {json}

some_url_executed('/', db_exec("select update_model(some_model);")

-- in database
create function update_model(json)

/* multiple tables to update for the model */
insert/update tables from json data
```

or option 2:

```
# in webserver

some_model = {json};

db_exec("begin transaction");
foreach field in some_model {
    db_exec("update some_table set value = some_model.value
}
dbexec("commit or rollback");
```

My data-model, if it matters, looks like:

```
{ fld1: {},
  ...
  fld5: { 'sub-fields' : { 'nested':'values' } } 
  fld6: [ {...}, {...} ]
}
```

I like the idea of letting the database handle this because I can grant permissions on that function to the user/group in the database (they shouldn't be allowed to navigate to the url anyway) but, yea - could use some guidance.

Back to the question, is it a bad idea to loop through a json object and insert/update from a stored procedure? Where does this logic belong? I'm using postgresql 9.5.

Comment: The question is somehow broad for an answer. I would choose 2nd approach. Because in 1st one, basic CRUD operations are costly. I would save my DB's cpu power to something else instead. Moreover, how will you version your data model changes in 1st approach?

Comment: i would choose 1. model because from my experience you cant trust front-end coders to write prober sql and in this  case i would have only one point where i need to make changes to sql. I would also create program1.0 schema and data schema to separate data and procedures. It also allows you to develop program2.0 schema prcedures and run 1.0 and 2.0 versions on same db. But i consider myself more of DB guy and server dev than front-end developer

Comment: Having the app call the db once per value will add a lot of network overhead into the transaction. I do mean a lot. As a first approach I would send the json en masse. If the db is prohibitively more expensive, and is approaching saturation, then do value by value as a cost saving, but not a performance, exercise.

Comment: @simplexio, I'm barely a front-end coder and now I'm tasked with writing sql..., good thing there's places like this to guide those not in the know along, appreciate the input.

Comment: @MichaelGreen, thanks - I stumbled across  [populate multiple tables from a single json object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27043450/722238), I'm going to go with that - so option 1 it is!